# How to setup custom middleware in strapi?

Tags: middleware, strapi

I just wanted to setup a simple custom middleware in strapi. I have tried what they are writing in docs but I found that environments folder and inside configurations are removed. Follwing that currently I have writtent.

*/config/environments/development/middleware.json*

```js
{
  "subscribers": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

*/config/middleware.json*

```js
{
  "timeout": 100,
  "load": {
    "before": ["responseTime", "logger", "cors", "responses", "gzip"],
    "order": ["parser", "subscribers"],
    "after": ["router"]
  }
}
```

*/middlewares/subscribers/index.js*

```js
module.exports = (strapi) => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        console.log("I have been called!");
        await next();
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Please help me to implement a middleware in strapi API. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The folder paths you are referencing are for the old beta version which isn't supported. Have you taken a look at the current stable docs?

Comment: Yeap. I have read it through https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/middlewares.html

Comment: I found another docs as well: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/middlewares.html#response-middlewares
Let me try it

Comment: hi Max what configuration in the middleware would like to change? please elaborate

Comment: Hi ghosh, I could make it work finally thanks to @Derrick Mehaffy. As he mentioned I was using wrong version of the docs and finally found the version from the source where  I expected to read. Thanks anyway. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I just did what is written in the docs and I will do the same in my answer!**

Initially I was reading from an older version of documentation which is mentioned by @Derrick Mehaffy. I found the correct docs url and read through its middleware implementation. [[LINK TO THE DOCS]](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/middlewares.html#response-middlewares) (Below explanations are obtained from docs)

---

> **Examples**: Create your custom middleware. [Path — *./middlewares/timer/index.js*]

```js
module.exports = strapi => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        const start = Date.now();
        // I just add custom code that logs `I have been called!`
        console.log('I have been called!');
        await next();

        const delta = Math.ceil(Date.now() - start);

        ctx.set('X-Response-Time', delta + 'ms');
      });
    },
  };
};
```

> Enable the middleware in environments settings.
>
> Load a middleware at the very first place - !You can do at the proper order
>
> Path — ./config/middleware.js

```js
module.exports = {
  load: {
    before: ["timer", "responseTime", "logger", "cors", "responses", "gzip"],
    order: ["parser", ],
    after: ["router", ],
  },
  settings: {
    timer: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
};
```

*Basically I just copied and pasted the answer from docs, but it might be helpful for future use that's I have left the question*